# about calling native method in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

Really need help. I am stuck here. Thank you for any suggestion here.

I am using NDK to build a so library then call it in java. But I can only call it in the mainactivity which is the start up activity, if I try to call it in another activity which is initiated by the mainactivity, it will fail. I call the method in the `OnCreate` method of each activity, the code is very simple as following:

```
System.loadLibrary("svm-predict");           
double dd = predictbattery("fsdfsdf", "sdfsdf", 0);
```

The stack for the error is:

```
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: predictbattery
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.dash.RunningLogActivity.predictbattery(Native Method)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.dash.RunningLogActivity.onCreate(RunningLogActivity.java:58)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-08 00:47:08.153: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

The method signatures in JNI C files  contain the package name and class name as well. So you cannot call the same function from different activities / classes.

eg.

```
JNIEXPORT float JNICALL
Java_com_artifex_mupdf_MuPDFCore_getPageWidth(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{ }
```

This JNI method 'getPageWidth() 'can be called only from

```
com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore
```

class. Hence, you are able to call it only from your main activity.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can also call the native method as `dd = com.dash.MainActivity.predictbattery( "fsdfsdf", "sdfsdf", 0); ` - only make sure that the native method in MainActivity class is declared as **public static**